# jQuery passing variable to new page via POST without forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I was looking for a way to pass a variable to a new page by POST method WITHOUT using a form.

Using GET is easy:

```
$("#my_link").click(function(){
    var name = 'John';
    var url = "my_new_page.php?name=" +name;
    window.open(url);
});
```

**How can I do the same thing with POST?**

I tried .load(), .post() and .ajax() but it didn't work.

Is it possible?

---

**SOLUTION:**

People marked my question as duplicate but that didn't solve my problem.
My thanks to SLaks, it seems that `<form>` is the only way.

I made this function that works just fine:

```
function post2blank(url,myarray)
{   var myform = '<form id="temporary_form" action="' +url+ '" target="_blank" method="POST">';
    $.each(myarray, function( key, value ){myform += '<input name="' +key+ '" value="' +value+ '"/>';});
    myform += '</form>';
    $(myform).appendTo('body').submit();
    $('#temporary_form').remove();
}
```

It creates a `<form>` with id="temporary_form" and append it to `<body>`. After submit each variable on "myarray" to "result.php", it removes the form.

Here's an example how to call:

```
<a onclick="var myArray = { name : 'John' , age : '45'}; post2blank('result.php' , myArray);">POST</a>
```

I tested on Chrome, IE10 and Firefox for android. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a hidden form and call `submit()`.

The `<form>` tag is the only way to navigate to a page using a POST.